# Objective C, why declare method in the interface

Tags: objective-c

I just started reading my first Objective-C book and it's mostly pretty clear, however I want to understand why it teaches me to declare a method in the interface first, I've tried deleting it from the interface and just doing it in the implementation section and all seems to work so my question is does it matter and if so, what does this help to accomplish?

Comment: *shrug* It probably teaches about separating the interface and implementations later. Don't worry about it-  It's probably just simplified now to allow new programmers to jump in more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's C. Declaring functions/methods in a header allows other compilation units to see your function prototypes and compile based on them. Objective-C works via dynamic dispatch though, so even if you don't declare a method in the header, it still exists at runtime. When you call a method, it is resolved at runtime, so it doesn't matter if it was in the header or not.

The only issue is, if you don't include the method in the header, the compiler has to make assumptions about the return and argument types. It defaults to `id`, which is 4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture, and therefore you will get into trouble if the actual return type is of a different size (e.g. structs or `BOOL` etc).

Comment: I've tried but have not gotten into trouble when the actual return type is of a different size(both tried struct and BOOL), could you explain this? Or this is a potential problem?

Comment: well, its more a problem if the actual return size is **greater** than  the size of `id` on your platform. In that case, the wrong version of `objc_msgSend` will be used. Instead of using `objc_msgSend_stret` which is for structs, it will use plain-old `objc_msgSend`, and you will lose anything past the size of `id`

Comment: Could you give us a demo to illustrate it? I've tried a struct which contain 5 double, and I do get the last double's value.

Comment: this isn't something that will _always_ break, but it is almost definitely going to break somewhere. Just out of curiosity, are you calling this method from the same file its declared in? Or from another file?

Comment: I'm calling this method from the same file.

Comment: Hah! that's why. As I explained in my answer, this only applies to different compilation units. You should observe the same behavior if your method call comes before your method declaration, try it out. The compiler will warn you that return type defaults to `id`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19124/discussion-between-sunkehappy-and-yfrancis)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your methods in the interface (header) to make it public (accessible by/from other classes). If you're using a method internally in your class only, you don't have to declare it in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is a highly dynamic language (and runtime) that defers the decision-making to as late as possible.

The code runs fine because at runtime the object does actually respond to the selector you've specified.

By declaring methods, however, you can help the Objective-C compiler to provide you with help in checking that you won't encounter any unexpected situations at runtime.

For example, take the following class:

```
@interface MDFoo : NSObject
- (void)blah;
@end


@implementation MDFoo

- (void)blah {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

- (void)boo {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

@end
```

Let's say that in another controller class, you create an instance of `MDFoo` and want to send it some messages.

```
MDFoo *foo = [[MDFoo alloc] init];
[foo blah];
[foo boo]; // compiler warning
[foo yell]; // compiler warning
```

When you compile the program, the compiler should give you a warning that both of the last two methods can't be found and that an instance of `MDFoo` may not respond to those selectors.

If you then run the program, the following is what's logged:

```
foo[10540:303] [MDFoo blah]
foo[10540:303] [MDFoo boo]
foo[10540:303] -[MDFoo yell]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001082f0
foo[10540:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
            'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MDFoo yell]:
                 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001082f0'
```

So at runtime the warning about `boo` turned out to be nothing, but the warning about `yell` was correct and caused the application to terminate.

From a design standpoint, it's also how you let other objects know what messages can be called. (See [Objective-C Programming Language: Defining a Class - The Role of the Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF125)).

Comment: Could explain what kind of unexpected situation?